# Using javascript/AJAX in MVC Razor View?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am supposed to convert a form submission from MVC Razor submission to an Ajax submission but I am having trouble even using simple javascript functions in the view of the form (Add.cshtml).

For starters, I try to link the JS file that i want to use in the following way:

```
@section JavaScript
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/ajax_submit.js")"></script>
}
```

The javascript file looks like this:

```
function dosubmit() {
    $("#add_address").ajaxForm({ url: '~/Home/Add', type: 'post' })
    alert("IT WORKS");
    return false;// if it's a link to prevent post
}
```

and I have my form built in the following way:

```
@model MvcApplicationTest.Models.PersonModel
@section JavaScript
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/ajax_submit.js")"></script>
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Hinzufügen";
}



<h2>Hinzufügen</h2>


<form id="add_address">

    <div class="fieldrow">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nachname)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nachname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Nachname)
    </div>
    <div class="fieldrow">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Vorname)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Vorname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Vorname)
    </div>
    <div class="fieldrow">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Strasse)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Strasse)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Strasse)
    </div>
    <div class="fieldrow">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Hausnummer)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Hausnummer)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Hausnummer)
    </div>
    <div class="fieldrow">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Plz)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Plz)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Plz)
    </div>
    <div class="fieldrow">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Ort)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Ort)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Ort)
    </div>
    <!--Martin-->
    <div class="fieldrow">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email) 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="dosubmit()" value="Speichern"  />
</form>
```

However, when I click the button nothing happens (it should pop up a window with the desired text).

I have tried to include the JS file into the _Layout.cshtml, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to call `.ajaxForm` on the form itself when the document is ready. `.ajaxForm` by itself just *prepares* the form for ajax submission, so by the time the submit button has been pressed, it's already too late.

I'd remove the submit handler from the `submit` button (I'd also use an `input` of type `submit` here):

```
<input type="submit" value="Speichern"  />
```

and add the following:

```
$(function () {
    $("#add_address").ajaxForm({ 
        url: '~/Home/Add', 
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            alert('about to submit');
        },
        type: 'post' 
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could use `.ajaxSubmit` instead of `.ajaxForm`:

```
function dosubmit() {
    $("#add_address").ajaxSubmit({ url: '~/Home/Add', type: 'post' });
    alert("IT WORKS");
    return false;// if it's a link to prevent post
}
```

Comment: I think `url:` should be `url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Home")',`.

Comment: That's a question for the OP. I'm not sure what the URL should be, just grabbed it from his original code.

Comment: The problem still persists when I include the <script></script> with the .ajaxForm you have written. When I press the button still nothing happens (it still has the dosubmit() handler as onclick).

Comment: None, but now I changed the button to type submit, and changed the URL and user1477388 suggested (it seems more logical to me that it's done this way)

'@Url.Action("Add", "Home")'

and the result is that it actually updates the StringQuery, but it does not executed the ActionResult from the Controller. @AndrewWhitaker